# Google Maps API: Reference to markers using setDirections

Tags: google-maps-api-3

With the Google Maps Javascript API, one can display markers and directions between them using `DirectionsService` and `DirectionsRenderer` ([examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions))

```
const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()

const mapOptions = {
  zoom:7,
  center: loc // some coordinates
}
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)
directionsDisplay.setMap(map)

const request = {
  origin: start, // some coordinates
  destination: end, // some coordinates
  travelMode: 'DRIVING'
}

directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result)
  }
})
```

The above will show two markers (start, end) on the map with the highlighted route between them. What I need is a reference to each of the markers created (to set custom labels, register events, etc). Any way to do this while still using `directionsDisplay.setDirections(result)` or would I need to create everything manually?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as there is a [long-standing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35819174) to have this functionality added to the `DirectionsRenderer`. You'll have to create the markers/polylines manually on the map from the `geocoded_waypoints` and `routes` returned in the [`DirectionsResult`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/directions#DirectionsResult)

Comment: @Preston can you send me reference to example how to create the markers/polylines manually on the map from the geocoded_waypoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (easily/safely) get references to the markers.  You can set the `suppressMarkers` option of the `DirectionsRenderer`, then create your own "custom" markers, from the data in the response.

```
 directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    createMarker(result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location, "A", "start marker", map, infowindow);
    var lastLeg = result.routes[0].legs.length - 1;
    createMarker(result.routes[0].legs[lastLeg].end_location, "B", "end marker", map, infowindow);
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/a4xrwn07/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419) // some coordinates
  }
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map)

  const request = {
    origin: {
      lat: 37.4418834,
      lng: -122.1430195
    }, // some coordinates
    destination: {
      lat: 37.4529598,
      lng: -122.1817252
    }, // some coordinates
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }

  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
      createMarker(result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location, "A", "start marker", map, infowindow);
      var lastLeg = result.routes[0].legs.length - 1;
      createMarker(result.routes[0].legs[lastLeg].end_location, "B", "end marker", map, infowindow);
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
// Adds a marker to the map.
function createMarker(location, label, content, map, infowindow) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: label,
    title: label,
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  })
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```